# define timeout on org.scalatest.FunSuite

Tags: scala, scalatest

JUnit allows tests that 'runaway' or take too long, to be automatically failed (https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/timeout-for-tests). Example:

```
@Test(timeout=1000)
public void testWithTimeout() {
  ...
}
```

How can I define a timeput using `org.scalatest.FunSuite`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `failAfter` from the [`Timeouts`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/concurrent/Timeouts$.html) trait:

```
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Timeouts
import org.scalatest.time.{Span, Millis}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class MyTest extends FlatSpec with Timeouts {

  "This test" should "do smhtg" in {

    // Here the timeout is 100ms
    failAfter(Span(100, Millis)) {
      // fails due to timeout:
      Thread.sleep(200)
      // or succeeds before timeout:
      // assert(true)
      // or fails before timeout:
      // assert(1 === 2)
    }
  }
}
```

which will thus fail, because it timeouts.